# Csv diff using powershell and showing (highlighting) changes on the new file

Tags: powershell, csv, diff

I have two csv files i need to compare them, then output a new file that will have the new values of the prophetess that changes and will mark(highlight) those properties some how. I already have the resulting file with all the values and all the properties but i dont know how to mark the specific properties that changed. Is there a way to do that is powershell?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
[CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $file1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $file2
    )
    $content1 = Import-Csv -Path $file1
    $content2 = Import-Csv -Path $file2
    $props = $content1 | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    $comparedLines = Compare-Object $content1 $content2 -Property $props -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } 

    $comparedLines | Export-csv -Path C:\FullPUF\Difference.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand this correctly, `$content2` is the newer file, right?

If so, then `$comparedlines` is going to contain all of the values which changed.  If that's right, then we're in business, because Doug Finke wrote an absolutely awesome PowerShell module called [importExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) that is going to make this trivially easy.  But first, how did I do this?

I needed some files to test against, and I didn't have your source file so I couldn't guess at the values.  I just made a simple CSV with a Name and Position value, and changed the Position numbers between Content1 and Content2.

[image]

How to solve this problem, first off, download Import-Excel right now.  If you're on PowerShell version 4.0 or higher you can install it from PowerShell like so:

```
Find-Module ImportExcel | Install-Module
```

This module has the concept of ConditionalText filter rules.  You can create a new one like this.

```
1..5 | Export-Excel C:\temp\test.xslx -Show`
  -ConditionalText (New-ConditionalText -ConditionType GreaterThan 3)
```

This will output and display a new spreadsheet with the numbers 1 through 5 in it, and highlight the ones higher than 3.

We can *also* highlight rows that ContainsText which matches a value we know.

So, we take the value of $comparedLines using ForEach-Object, and create a New-ConditionalText rule to highlight the line if it contains one of the properties.

```
$highlight =$comparedLines | % {New-ConditionalText -ConditionalType ContainsText $_.Name}
```

Next, we will echo the contents of $content2, and use Export-Excel to create a new .xslx file and apply a conditional formatting rule to it.

```
$content2 | Export-Excel r:\test.xlsx -show -ConditionalText ($highlight)
```

And the output

[image]

You'll probably need to play with the code a tiny bit, and modify it to fit whatever your columns are called, but this is how you can export a csv and highlight the differences using PowerShell.  Except there's no such thing as highlighting or text format in a .csv so you have to use an Excel SpreadSheet instead.

Lemme know if you need me to dig deeper anywhere :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion FoxDeploy. As You said $content2 is the newer file, meaning $content1 is the old file. And the lines that have changed between then are in $comparedLines. Now, in my scenario i do not know which specific properties have changed from the old file to the new file, and i will like to have a way to figure this out dynamically.  So in the outputfile i will like to have the specific cell colored if there was a changed from the old file to the new one, Something similar to you result file but with the cell where the change happened(which is in the Rank Property)  colored

Comment: To help you any further, I will need copies of your input files.  As is, I think this gets you headed in the right direction, and is probably worthy of being marked 'Answer', don't you? :)